# Remote disk samba, no rw and no gui

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, samba, networkmanager

I want to mount a remote disk at boot time with fstab and have it appear in thunar, which is not the case

My config :

> Distro: Arch Linux
>
> Desktop: Xfce version: 4.18.0 x86_64 bits
>
> Kernel: 6.1.1-arch1-1

My fstab :

> cat /etc/fstab | grep //
>
> //192.168.1.254/sauvegarde/Stockage/
> /mnt/Stockage cifs
> noauto,x-systemd.automount,credentials=/root/.credentials,iocharset=utf8,nounix,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770
> 0 0
>
> //192.168.1.254/sauvegarde/.Bruno/ /mnt/Sauvegarde cifs
> noauto,x-systemd.automount,credentials=/root/.credentials,iocharset=utf8,nounix,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770
> 0 0

My smb.conf file (without comments) :

> [global]
>
> workgroup = WORKGROUP
>
> server string = Samba Server
>
> server role = standalone server
>
> hosts allow = 192.168.1. 192.168.2. 127.
>
> log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
>
> max log size = 50
>
> security = user
> map to guest = bad user
> guest account = guest
>
> usershare path = /var/lib/samba/usershares
> usershare max shares = 100
> usershare allow guests = yes
> usershare owner only = yes
>
> server min protocol = SMB2_02
>
> wins support = yes
>
> dns proxy = no

[image: systemctl status smb]

[image: systemctl status nmb]

[image: systemctl status disk]

[image: ls -al path disk]

the disks are well mounted in the directory, but impossible to write to

My second problem is that the discs do not appear in Thunar.

[image: thunar]

No problem to access the disk directly from thunar :

[image: thunar mount]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Images of thunar, fair enough, but the text from others should be copied and pasted so they're readable